# JS shake and fade button that doesn´t work. What´s wrong with this code?

Tags: javascript

I´m trying a JS example that I´ve found in a book, and for some reason it doesn´t work. I´ve checked for typos also. I´m not using any particular library.

**It´s a button that should shake and fade after clicking it. And it does none of those things.**

**(Here´s the [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Rosamunda/vpSnw/))**

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="shake(this, fadeOut);">Shake and Fade</button>
```

**JS**

```
function shake(e, oncomplete, distance, time) {
    if (typeof e === "string") e = document.getElementById(e);
    if (!time) time = 500;
    if (!distance) distance = 5;

    var originalStyle = e.style.cssText;
    e.style.position = "relative";
    var start = (new Date()).getTime();
    animate();

    function animate() {
        var now = (new Date()).getTime();
        var elapsed = now - start;
        var fraction = elapsed / time;

        if (fraction < 1) {
            var x = distance * Math.sin(fraction * 4 * Math.PI);
            e.style.left = x + "px";

            setTimeout(animate, Math.min(25, time - elapsed));
        } else {
            e.style.cssText = originalStyle;
            if (oncomplete) oncomplete(e);
        }
    }
}

function fadeOut(e, oncomplete, time) {
    if (typeof e === "string") e = document.getElementById(e);
    if (!time) time = 500;

    var ease = Math.sqrt;

    var start = (net Date()).getTime();
    animate();

    function animate() {
        var elapsed = (new Date()).getTime() - start;
        var fraction = elapsed / time;
        if (fraction < 1) {
            var opacity = 1 - ease(fraction);
            e.style.opacity = String(opacity);
            setTimeout(animate,
            Math.min(25, time - elapsed));
        } else {
            e.style.opacity = "0";
            if (oncomplete) oncomplete(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the error console, your code has a syntax error.

```
var start = (net Date()).getTime();
```

Should be:

```
var start = (new Date()).getTime();
```

Comment: Can´t belive it was a typo! THANKS!! It works now :)